# how to add generic before and after callbacks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a few functions in a class. For each function, I want to be able to specify what if anything should be called before executing it, and what if anything to be called after executing it.

For example, suppose my functions are a, b, c, d, and e. I want to do something like the following:

```
before: [:a, :b, :c], execute: :before_func
after: [d, e], execute: :after_func
```

Is there a gem or a technique I can use to accomplish the above?

Background:

My class is basically a class that reads files from ftp. I have declared an @ftp variable that is initialized when a class instance is created, and then when needed it tries to read from ftp, or do other operations on ftp. Now if the operations happen close together it works but otherwise it gives a timeout. So before each function i want to close the current @ftp, and reopen a new connection and use that. when the function ends i want to close the ftp connection. I have already written most functions so want to just declare two functions, one to open connections and one to close connections.

Comment: wrap your methods in blocks

Answer (score 2):

You could use some ruby meta programming via `define_method` and `alias_method_chain`, something like this perhaps:

```
module MethodHooks

  def before(*symbols)
    hook=symbols.pop
    symbols.each { |meth|
      define_method :"#{meth}_with_before_#{hook}" do |*args, &block|
        self.send hook, *args, &block
        self.send :"#{meth}_without_before_#{hook}", *args, &block
      end
      alias_method_chain meth, :"before_#{hook}"
    }
  end

  def after(*symbols)
    hook=symbols.pop
    symbols.each { |meth|
      define_method :"#{meth}_with_after_#{hook}" do |*args, &block|
        self.send :"#{meth}_without_after_#{hook}", *args, &block
        self.send hook, *args, &block
      end
      alias_method_chain meth, :"after_#{hook}"
    }
  end
end

Object.extend(MethodHooks)
```

Then to use it in an arbitrary class:

```
before :a, :b, :c, :before_func
after :a, :b, :c, :after_func
```

The above (untested) code demonstrates the idea for hooking instance methods, but you could also adapt for class methods if required.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are looking to do Aspect Oriented Programming in Rails.

Perhaps this gem might help https://github.com/davesims/simple-aop